# Clustered index and Non clustered index

Tags: sql-server, index

This might be a silly question but i really want to know the internals.This is one of small table just to test as below

[image]

I have create a table as above and 'name' column is primary key and clustered index so it has sort all words in alphabetical order . Now when i create a non clustered index on column 'number' , the rows in 'name' column not anymore in alphabetical order as below

[image]

My question is, the name column should remain the rows in alphabetical order rite since it has clustered index and how come it changed after i add non clustered index on different column? i m sure there might be certain things i missed.Please let me know.Thank you

Comment: Rows in a relation database have no order. If you want a guaranteed sort order, you **have** to use `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of your data returned is **not** guaranteed when you do not specify an order by.

Consider this example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SmallTable([name] varchar(25) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                            Number int);

INSERT INTO dbo.SmallTable ([name],[Number]) VALUES ('compi',15 ), ('jack',5 ), ('malik',20 ), ('nana',10 );
```

If you were to just select without an order by:

```
SELECT [name],[Number] 
FROM dbo.SmallTable;
```

The order this time is the same as your first example:

```
name    Number
compi   15
jack    5
malik   20
nana    10
```

But this is not guaranteed.

If you want the ordering to be guaranteed then you need to add an order by:

```
SELECT [name],[Number] 
FROM dbo.SmallTable
ORDER BY [name] ASC;
```

What you are seeing when creating the nonclustered index on number is the query using this new NC index.

For example:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Number
on dbo.SmallTable(Number);
```

Running the query again:

```
SELECT [name],[Number] 
FROM dbo.SmallTable;
```

I get the same result as you:

```
name    Number
jack    5
nana    10
compi   15
malik   20
```

Because now sql server decides to use the `IX_Number` index to return the results:

[image]

Which is ordered by `number asc`.

To guarantee the ordering the query needs to be changed to:

```
SELECT [name],[Number] 
FROM dbo.SmallTable;
ORDER BY [name] asc;
```

The ordering could even be different than the index order from the index that was used. This means that even if now the ordering is on the `number` or `name` column, it could be on any one of these columns or even none.

Always use an `order by` if the ordering is important.

More info on the subject can be found [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/why-order-isnt-guaranteed-without-an-order-by/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050341/when-no-order-by-is-specified-what-order-does-a-query-choose-for-your-record), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/conor_cunningham_msft/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86596/in-sql-server-can-i-guarantee-an-order-without-an-explicit-order-by-clause-when)